# Snakemake deletes the temp files prematurely, while running with --immediate-submit option

Tags: job-scheduling, snakemake, sbatch

While I submit jobs with `--immediate-submit` and `--dependency=afterok:{dependencies}`, the temp files are getting deleted even before the rules that depend on temp files are started. It's working perfectly when running in normal way. Does any other came across this issue?

**Snakemake script**

```
rule all:
    input: 'file2', 'file3'

rule one:
    input: 'file1'
    output: temp('file2')
    shell: "touch {output}"

rule two:
    input: 'file2'
    output: 'file3'
    shell: "touch {output}"
```

**Submission command**

```
snakemake -s sample.snake --cluster '../mybatch.py {dependencies}' -j 4 --immediate-submit
```

**Snakemake output message**

```
Provided cluster nodes: 4
Job counts:
        count   jobs
        1       all
        1       one
        1       two
        3

rule one:
    input: file1
    output: file2
    jobid: 1


rule two:
    input: file2
    output: file3
    jobid: 2


localrule all:
    input: file2, file3
    jobid: 0

Removing temporary output file file2.
Finished job 0.
1 of 3 steps (33%) done

Removing temporary output file file2.
Finished job 1.
2 of 3 steps (67%) done

localrule all:
    input: file2, file3
    jobid: 0

Removing temporary output file file2.
Finished job 0.
3 of 3 steps (100%) done
Error in job two while creating output file file3.
ClusterJobException in line 9 of /faststorage/home/veera/pipelines/ipsych-GATK/test/sample.snake:
Error executing rule two on cluster (jobid: 2, jobscript: /faststorage/home/veera/pipelines/ipsych-GATK/test/.snakemake/tmp.cmvmr3lz/snakejob.two.2.sh). For
detailed error see the cluster log.
Will exit after finishing currently running jobs.
```

**Error message**

```
Missing files after 5 seconds:
file2
/faststorage/home/veera/pipelines/ipsych-GATK/test/.snakemake/tmp.jqh2qz0n
touch: cannot touch `/faststorage/home/veera/pipelines/ipsych-GATK/test/.snakemake/tmp.jqh2qz0n/1.jobfailed': No such file or directory
Missing files after 5 seconds:
file2
```

The jobs are being submitted with proper dependency. The ../mybatch.py is custom wrapper script for sbatch. Is this a bug or error in my code? Thanks for the help in advance.